# Why isn't my new payment method showing up on one-page-checkout in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I have followed the tutorial located in the wiki: 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/payment/create-payment-method-module

The module is visible in the backend.
This means, the "`Config->advanced->advanced`", and "`config->Payment Methods`" tabs of the backend both function properly.  After setting the module to active, I go through the checkout process on the frontend and it doesn't show up.

I have tried the module twice.  One with the desired company and module names I chose, another with the default names from the wiki.  Neither of them work on the frontend.

Did I miss something?  Have others followed the wiki and had it work with the onepagecheckout?

I have checked my error logs but saw no error produced.

I have delayed posting my code because they are the exact same as the wiki article linked above.  But I will post code if requested.

Comment: Stupid question, but have you flushed cache?

Comment: I have caching turned completely off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I needed to define a Block and create the form.phtml file corresponding to my payment module.

An example I used to get mine working is located here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/230559/

It is apparently "known" that the wiki is incomplete, according to the author of the above post on another thread:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/230704/#t326542